# How to Configure and Use Multi-DataSource Routing with Spring Boot and JPA? No table is getting created in DB2 save not working forDB1

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I'm working on a Spring Boot application where I need to route to different data sources based on certain conditions. Specifically, I want to route to different databases when saving StudentEntity instances, depending on a given condition. Below is my current setup:

```
  @Override
    public StudentEntity saveStudent(StudentEntity studentEntity,String db) {
        StudentEntity save = null;
        if(db.equals("DB1")) {
            DBContextHolder.setCurrentDb(ClientNames.DB1);
             save = studentRepository.save(studentEntity);
        }
        else{
            DBContextHolder.setCurrentDb(ClientNames.DB2);
            save = studentRepository.save(studentEntity);
        }
        return save;
    }
```

//Data base configuration

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource({"classpath:application.properties"})
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "multiEntityManager",
        transactionManagerRef = "multiTransactionManager")
@EntityScan("com.demo.MyDemo.model")
public class DatabaseConfiguration {
    private final String PACKAGE_SCAN = "com.demo.MyDemo.model";

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "db1DataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource")
    public DataSource db1DataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().type(HikariDataSource.class).build();
    }

    //connection objects for the remaining 2 databases

    @Bean(name = "db2DataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties("app.datasource.db2")

    public DataSource db2DataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().type(HikariDataSource.class).build();
    }


    @Bean(name = "multiRoutingDataSource")
    public DataSource multiRoutingDataSource() {
        Map<Object, Object> targetDataSources = new HashMap<>();
        targetDataSources.put(ClientNames.DB1, db1DataSource());
        targetDataSources.put(ClientNames.DB2, db2DataSource());

        MultiRoutingDataSource multiRoutingDataSource
                = new MultiRoutingDataSource();
        multiRoutingDataSource.setDefaultTargetDataSource(db1DataSource());
        multiRoutingDataSource.setTargetDataSources(targetDataSources);
        return multiRoutingDataSource;
    }

    @Bean(name = "multiEntityManager")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean multiEntityManager() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em
                = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(multiRoutingDataSource());
        em.setPackagesToScan(PACKAGE_SCAN);
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter
                = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        em.setJpaProperties(hibernateProperties());
        return em;
    }

    @Bean(name = "transactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager multiTransactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager
                = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(
                multiEntityManager().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name="entityManagerFactory")
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean dbSessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(multiRoutingDataSource());
        sessionFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(PACKAGE_SCAN);
        sessionFactoryBean.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
        return sessionFactoryBean;
    }

    private Properties hibernateProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        //properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", true);
        //properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", true);
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect");
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create");
        properties.put("hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings", false);
        properties.put("hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation", true);
        return properties;
    }


}
```

//application.properties

```
spring.datasource.jdbc-url= jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydemo
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root

app.datasource.db2.jdbc-url= jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydemolocal
app.datasource.db2.username=root
app.datasource.db2.password=root
app.datasource.db2.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
app.datasource.db2.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

//ServiceImpl

```
  @Override
    public StudentEntity saveStudent(StudentEntity studentEntity,String db) {
        StudentEntity save = null;
        if(db.equals("DB1")) {
            DBContextHolder.setCurrentDb(ClientNames.DB1);
             save = studentRepository.save(studentEntity);
        }
        else{
            DBContextHolder.setCurrentDb(ClientNames.DB2);
            save = studentRepository.save(studentEntity);
        }
        return save;
    }
```

I want data to be saved in either of the DB's on based of condition in implementation method

Comment: This link may help: https://www.baeldung.com/multitenancy-with-spring-data-jpa

Comment: thanks for the link I will definitely try the approach mean while if any one has any idea about my code please help

Comment: The approach is off because you are switching a DB context out from under something that assumes only a single DB - DDL is executed when JPA starts up, and doesn't know about your second database context. You'd need to have a persistence units overtop of each database, and switch between them. Alternatively, you'd need your own startup logic that goes through every DB and manually creates the DB via JPA Persistence.generateSchema method. I'm not sure what is going wrong with your code when it comes to saves to db1 though - you'll have to check how transactions are behaving.